# Can I create more than 1 table at a time in a SQLite query in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, air, create-table

Whenever I try to create more than one table in actionscript, only the first one gets run.
I've been using a string for my query or embedding an external file with the SQL code, and every time AS seems to ignore everything after the first ;

Perhaps this is a feature of Actionscript and how it deals with databases and adding each table is a separate query, but is there a way to get around this? I like the idea of having my whole db CREATE statement set in one contained place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that multiple statements [aren't supported](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2139108) in AIR SQLite commands. You might separate your scripts into statements and execute them sequentially.